# jQuery Ajax form not posting data to controller (Codeigniter)

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I have a page where users can write reviews about certain websites. 
I need to post this data to my Codeigniter controller, which uses a model function to insert the data to a database. 
Everything worked fine until I added the jquery and now it doesn't post, and doesn't seem to go to the controller at all. Any help fixing this will be appreciated. Thanks.

**html**

```
<table id="revForm">
    <tr>
        <td>Site reviewed:</td>
        <td><input readonly type="text" id="site" name="profile" value="<?php echo $sitename; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Enter name"> </td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Message:</td>
        <td><textarea row="6" column="40" id="message" name="message" value="message"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rate this site</td> 
        <td>
            <div>                        
                <input name="rating" type="radio" value="1" class="star"/>
                <input name="rating" type="radio" value="2" class="star"/>
                <input name="rating" type="radio" value="3" class="star"/>
                <input name="rating" type="radio" value="4" class="star"/>
                <input name="rating" type="radio" value="5" class="star"/>                    
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table><br>
<button id="submitReview2">Submit</button><br/>
```

**Controller 'reviews'**

```
public function addReview() { 

    $this->load->helper('form');         
    if ($this->input->post("message")!="")  {
            $this->reviewsMod->addReview($this->input->post('profile'),
                                    $this->input->post('name'),
                                    $this->input->post('message'),
                                    date('d/m/Y'),
                                    $this->input->post('rating'));
            $data['sitename'] = $this->input->post('profile');
            $this->load->view('shared/header');
            $this->load->view('profile', $data );
            $this->load->view('shared/footer');                            
        }

        else {
            $this->load->view('shared/header', $session);
            $this->load->view('profile', $data);
            $this->load->view('shared/footer'); 
            }      
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#submitReview2').click(function() {
    var profile = $('#site').val();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var message = $('#msg').val();
    var rating = $('#rating').val();

    var msgData = {
       'profile':profile,
       'name':name,
       'message':message,
       'rating':rating
    }
   var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
   $.ajax ({
       type: 'POST',
       url: base_url+'reviews/addReview',
       data:  msgData,
       success:
           function(){                   
                $('#revForm').html("<div id='success'></div>")
                $('#success').html("Your review has been submitted")
                .fadeIn(1500);
           }

  });
  return false;
```

**Model function**

```
public function addReview($profile, $name, $message, $stamp, $rating) {
   $this->setValues($profile, $name, $message, $stamp, $rating);
   $this->db->insert('messages', $this);
```

}

Comment: print the posted array[`print_r($_POST)`] in controller, check it in firebug

Comment: thanks, finally learned to work properly with firebug... discovered I was referring the wrong 'message' id in the jquery. I used 'msg' there as opposed to 'message' in the html. dumb mistake :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the url helper for the base_url() function?

`$this->load->helper('url');`

Also use chrome with and use the developertools to check "console" and "network".

Comment: I loaded it in the controller, was I supposed to do it somewhere else? in any case, also if I type in the full url it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I think thw `JQuery` post is does not work like this.
you need to use the Jquery `.submit()` or `.post()` methods.

please find the example and explanation of the `Jquery post()` and `submit()`

1.[Jquery submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
2.[Jquery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: .submit requires a submit button and I don't have one because this isn't a form. I understood I should use a regular <button> when using ajax, together with the the jquery .click()

Answer (score 0):

First of all specify the *error* handle for your ajax request so you can see what's happening after error occures:

```
$.ajax({
        //
        // Other parameters
        //
        success: function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Some code
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           // Some code to debbug e.g.:               
           console.log(jqXHR);
           console.log(textStatus);
           console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Also start using some kind of javascript debbuging tool (depends on the browser you're using) like someone said chrome developer tools (press f12 when being on website and go to network tab) in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox or even a more sophisticated desktop application like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

If you'll still have problem with posting data please give us some more information about error you've encountered